# Resources Management Linear Programming

Tags: linear-programming

I have a simple problem to solve. I need to allocate resources to three projects in such a way that we maximise resources efficiency. I need some help formulating the problem in an objective function.

More details of the problem:

All the projects will last 18 weeks. The three lists below define the demand for resources during the 18 weeks (18 x 5 = 90 days) across the 3 projects

```
Project_One =  [32  14  30  12  23  27  12  21  32  12  20  29  15  20  15  17  15  11] 
Project_Two =  [ 4  5   14  11  13  9   10  11  7   9   14  8   9   11  9   7   6   8]
Project_Three= [ 8  8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8];
```

We have a total of 48 contractor resources. We can let go of resources to minimise loss, however the cost of retraining is 10 days unproductivity.

How can I formulate a linear programming problem to get the amount of resources we need to keep every week to minimise overall cost. The objective function should take in consideration whether it's better to let go and retrain later or keep the resources to be used in later weeks as demand increases?

Some Key Information:

1) The cost of 1 resource is $100 per day.
2) New resources are trained by shadowing existing workers. For simplicity we assume that the cost is just 10 working days = $1000.
3) The cost of keeping the resources idle is the number of days between they are not required in any project and the next demand surge happens. Ideally we would not let go of the resource if the idle time is less than 10 days.

Comment: The problem is infeasible. You need more than 48 resources in period 3 and you have no time to train new ones. I assume all is days (your question talks about 18 weeks and 18 days which confuses me).

Comment: Erwin Kalvelagen. Many thanks for pointing this out. My mistake, it is 18 weeks, about 90 days. For simplicity, I kept it to 18 weeks, 90 days but usually the projects lasts on average 180 days.

Comment: I don't think this can be done with a pure LP. You will need some binary variables so yo end up with a MIP model. Also you need some cost information (cost of idle resources, cost of training).

Comment: Thanks for the headsup @ErwinKalvelagen. I will look into MIP. I have added the cost information above. What will the binary variables be?

Comment: I used  `h(i,t)` to indicate when someone is hired and `r(i,t)` to indicate if a resource is available (either for training or for work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My attempt using a MIP model looks like:

[image]

The results are:

[image]

We have 4 hires/trainees in week 1 (training in week 1 and 2, available for work in week 3) and 3 hires in week 7. You can see in the picture that the worker count goes up at the beginning of week 3 and 9.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ErwinKalvelagen. The solution looks very good. I have one quick question. In the objective function, shouldn't the constant multiplying the number of hires be higher than 1? If we assume the cost of hiring and training is higher than keeping resources for 2 weeks (which is a good assumption you made), then I would expect the constant to be higher than 1? Thank you.

Comment: `r(i,t)` is working, idle or training, so that is already there.

Comment: The orange line is sum `r` minus trainees.